# Best way to take 2 columns, and reorder the data by grouping

Tags: linux, bash

I have a query I run, and the data gets output like this:

```
seta set1
setb set2
setb set3
setc set4
setd set5
setd set6
setd set7
```

what I need it to look like in the end is this:

```
seta set1
setb set2
     set3
setc set4
setd set5
     set6
     set7
```

kinda like a tree I guess.  I can't really give a more detailed example due to the nature of my work.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{fmt="%-10s%s\n"}
     $1==last{printf fmt," ",$2; next }
     {printf fmt,$1,$2; last=$1}' file
seta      set1
setb      set2
          set3
setc      set4
setd      set5
          set6
          set7
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

first_word=''
last_word=''
while read line ; do
  first_word=`echo "$line" | sed 's/^\([^ ]\+\).*$/\1/'`
  if [ "$first_word" == "$last_word" ] ; then
    echo -n $first_word | tr "[:graph:]" " "
    echo "$line" | sed 's/^[^ ]\+\(.*\)$/\1/'
  else
    echo $line
    last_word="$first_word"
  fi
done
```